# Reactjs - Show loading image immediately after click on Link until child isn't fully rendered

Tags: reactjs, canvas, loading, render, fabricjs

I am rendering complex canvas with fabricjs. It takes few second, around 3+-. Is there way to render this page immediately without waiting for render, and show some loading image until canvas can be show instantly?

My parent's component -

```
class GraphPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            print: null
        }
    }

    render(){
        console.log('render');
        const graphList = graphStore.getGraphValue();
        var {data} = this.props;
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="inputs">
                    <Inputs modal={false} unit='%' list={graphList.rotation} descTitle={data.graph.machine}/>
                    <Inputs modal={false} unit='mm' list={graphList.machine} descTitle={data.graph.rotation}/>
                </div>
                <div className="graph">
                    <Print />
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`Print` is my canvas component.

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: this is my [graphPage](http://pastebin.com/HEpRSSAN) there i want to show loading image instead of Graph, until Graph si fully rendered(loaded)

Comment: I can show Graph component too, but its complex with a lot of childs like rect,column,grid and so on.. :D

Comment: You should put that code in your question directly.

Comment: Its not important how this component looks. There is normal rendering. I just ask for how i can show some image until the another component can be immediately show

Comment: Well it depends on how this component loads. That's why code is relevant. Besides, it's typically expected here that you provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

If `print` is the fabric JS component I would pass an `onLoaded` callback to it and then when the `fabric.Image` object is done loading you can call that function and set the `loaded` state for this component. Then this function can render something different based on that state.

Comment: How i can get know that fabric.Image is fully loaded ? And yep, Print is fabric js component.

Comment: On creating a fabric object you can pass in a callback.: `new fabric.Image(imageDomElement, options, onLoadCallback)` that callback can be a event passed down from a parent react object.